# Registry edition values of Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, autopilot

I want to obtain Windows 10 OS edition from registry. I'm reading below registry key using C# code to get it:

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EditionID
```

Here is the C# code:

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"))
{
     if (key != null)
     {
         var keyValue = key.GetValue("EditionID");
         var osEdition = keyValue.ToString();
     }
}
```

I need to  know the strings that'll be present in the **EditionID** key for various editions of Windows 10. I couldn't get any relevant Microsoft documentation around it. Major Windows 10 editions are as below:

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. Windows 10 Pro for Workstations
3. Windows 10 Education
4. Windows 10 Pro Education
5. Windows 10 Enterprise
6. Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTS/LTSC/LTSB
7. Windows 10 Home

I've an `Enterprise` edition Windows 10 OS on my PC. So I know that for `Enterprise` edition this registry values comes as `Enterprise`. I need to know the rest.

Comment: So basically you just want windows 10, have you tried using `Environment.OSVersion` and checking the major version is 10?

Comment: I can detect Windows 10 OS by reading `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentMajorVersionNumber` registry key . But I'm interested in specific editions of Windows 10 e.g. I want to know if it has `Pro for Workstations` edition or not.

Comment: I know you're currently focussed on the editions question but do you actually need the edition or do you need to know whether certain *windows features* are available, and you're using the former as a proxy for the latter? Because if so, you ought to switch to testing for features.

Comment: My problem is to figure out whether current machine OS can be registered with Windows Autopilot or not. Only some specific editions of Windows 10 and Windows 11 support it.  As far as I know, checking OS edition is the only way to know this. It will be really great if a feature check can tell me this capability. I've updated the title of the post to make my intentions more clear.

Comment: This seems like a very specific thing to check that might also change in the future. It's so specific that it's likely not worth checking for, but instead attempting to register it and see if it fails with the specific result that the version/edition of Windows is not supported.

Comment: That can be an idea but my current business problem is like that only. Going through the entire cycle of trying and failing will be too costly for the end-user in the problem I'm trying to solve. So I need the name of Windows 10 edition on the PC.

Comment: @RBT Better idea: why not use `msinfo32.exe`?

Comment: We read the registry directly or use `msinfo32.exe`, it won't matter. `msinfo32.exe` will also pick this information from registry only. Actual problem was that I did not have all editions of Windows installed in my office. So I was struggling to know the edition strings that I'll encounter when my application runs.

Comment: @RBT Microsoft could come out with a new Windows SKU tomorrow - what will you do then?

Comment: Yes. That'll invite code change. We've a switch case construct in code. Any unknown/new edition string maps to `default` case which says unsupported OS. But whenever our product has to support a new edition of Windows then it'll anyways invite a full regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to obtain some of them. Please feel free to edit this post if you find anyone installed in your office, school or home.

- Windows 10 Pro - **Professional**
- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations - **ProfessionalWorkstation**
- Windows 10 Education - **Education**
- Windows 10 Pro Education - **ProfessionalEducation**
- Windows 10 Enterprise - **Enterprise**
- Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTS/LTSC/LTSB - **EnterpriseS**
- Windows 10 Home - **Home**

Comment: These strings are in English - are they **always** in English in non-English builds of Windows? (Anyone else remember the pain of trying to parse Windows XP Service Pack strings?)

Answer (score 1):

I do know that Windows Enterprise LTSC has an EditionID of "EnterpriseS"

I found this out on a version that runs on the LattePanda.

Comment: Thank you Keziah for sharing your findings. Appreciate it. I've updated my own [wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69835922/465053) in this thread with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed
Windows 10 Pro for Workstations - `ProfessionalWorkstation`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How did you find this value? Did you see it on your own computer? If yes, then please post a screenshot. It'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Given the description of the problem you are trying to solve and the fact I am trying to do a similar thing, I've stumbled upon the Win32_OperatingSystem class in Instrumentation management.

```
var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var results = searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First();
```

After this you can use the "Caption" property to get the exact string of the edition of Windows that is installed.
I have three examples:

- 10 Enterprise Multisession = Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise for Virtual Desktops
- Regular 10 Enterprise = Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Server 2012R2 = Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

You can also dig around in that class' other properties to try and get the info that you need.